# Object declaration check in Java

Tags: java, object

My code snippet:

```
if (answer) {
 TourRequest tour = new TourRequest();
}
```

After the above statement, I want to declare tour object, using a different constructor if it hasn't already been declared inside the curly brackets.

How can I check directly if tour exist, without using the content of the answer variable?

Comment: Use an `else`? Create a duplicate variable? Why exactly don't you want to use `answer`? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: Ιf answer = false I want to  instantiate tour object at a different code section with a different constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable outside of the if statement and then check if it is null.

```java
TourRequest tour = null;
if(answer) {
  tour = new TourRequest();
}

if(tour == null) {
  tour = new TourRequest(/*params...*/);
}
```

Better yet, just use an else.

```java
TourRequest tour;
if(answer) {
  tour = new TourRequest();
}
else {
  tour = new TourRequest(/*params...*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplified solution is here

```java
TourRequest tour = answer ? new TourRequest() : new TourRequest(parameter);
```

Comment: Ιf answer = false I want to  instantiate tour object at a different code section with a different constructor. Perhaps I use a static boolean variable inside TourRequest class to be declared true the first time a parameterless constructor is used.

Comment: ............ like this: if (!TourRequest.isInstance()) {TourRequest tour = new TourRequest(area);} . However it doesn't seem to work, because in the next line of code tour is not recognized